# Customize SharePoint Online Discussion List

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

I change "New Discussion" link to "New Idea", but I can't change "My Discussion" text.

Answer (score 1):

> > Q-1
> >     Please provide more information about this question for further research.
> >
> > Q-2
> >     Here is a workaround for your reference.

First click “Edit page”.

[image]

Then, add a  “Script Editor” web part.
[image]

Next click “EDIT SNIPPET” to insert JS code into the web part.
[image]

My JS code below for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  function change(){
    if($("a:contains('My discussions')").length>0){
       $("a:contains('My discussions')").text("hello");
    }
  }
  $(function(){
      setInterval("change()", 200);
     });
</script>
```

Finally, click “Stop Editing” to save your changes and you will see what you want.
[image]

Screenshot of result:
[image]

Best regards

Lee Liu